# How to enable sound on fresh install of Arch Linux and xfce

Tags: arch-linux, xfce

I have installed pulseaudio and alsamixer. No luck in getting my laptop to make any sound. I'm a noob. What can I do? Please ask me further questions to understand my situation

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) for tips on how to ask questions. This question is very poor, as we lack a lot of info: what distro are you using? What have you tried so far? What's the output of the logs?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it already. I only needed to unmute alsamixer